# E.g.: or E.g: (punctuation)

Tags: punctuation

Which is correct?
I tried to learn the rules talking about using dots in the English language, but wasn't able to find any answer to my specific question.

1. I don't like lots of trees, e.g.:
2. I don't like lots of trees, e.g:

Comment: Hello, 470. 'The rules' isn't the right way to think about these grey areas of punctuation (ie in complex cases). Notice that I drop the full stops (periods), which is fine according to some modern style guides, especially, it seems, in the UK. But I've even seen the rule (sorry, advice): 'Don't use abbreviations deriving from the Latin.'

Comment: Did you forget to search our site for existing questions and answers about this?

Answer (score 0):

In this use case if you place a "dot" (period) after the "e" you should also place one after the "g". There is no requirement to use the dots and they may be omitted with generally no loss in understanding for most readers. There is also generally no consensus about punctuation between the "eg" and the example. Colon, comma and no punctuation work equally well.